# How to center python print

Tags: python, string, formatting

I have a string like follows

```
string = "I went to the market the other day"
vowels = "AEIOUaeiou"
vcount = 0

for letter in string:
    vcount+=1
print ("Vowels:", vcount)
```

how would I center the printed data using string.center

Comment: Center where? And relative to what?

Comment: When you know the size of the line you can do `print(content.center(line_size))`. Is this what you mean? However it isn't trivial to handle resizing etc. You should consider following Karoly suggestion if you want to handle these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.center`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.center) function to print in console center:

```
# Where 80 is default width of console in characters
print("Vowels: %s".center(80) % vcount)
```

Comment: Or using string formatting: `'Count: {:^80}'.format(vcount)`

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is center all values sit should look like Vowels: space space 3 when centered

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about centering on the screen:

The standard output is a stream, there's no concept of a "screen", there's no "width", hence you cannot center.

Use the [curses](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) package.

Alternatively, if you assume a fixed size (eg: 80 chars), it's a simple math calculation. You need (80-length)/2 spaces as a prefix.